# How to ask someone to make the level of the sound of a radio or a T.V higher?

Tags: word-request

If I'm watching the T.V with my friend or somebody and I want to ask him\her to make the level of the sound of the T.V or radio higher, How to express that soundly?

Could I say, "could you make the radio louder"? Is that ok? How to say that in everyday language?

By the way, What is better, The sound of radio (even if it's a human who is talking throw the radio) or the voice of a radio?

Comment: To answer your last question, it's the "volume" of the radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it up. 
Could you turn it up?

(These are natural, everyday expressions.)

You could also designate the program or content rather than the device (television or radio).

For example:

Turn the news up, I can't hear it.

The above sentence could refer to either a radio or television, or even computer speakers. But you are referring to the content of what you are listening to, rather than to the device you are listening to.)

Comment: And if you want the volume turned way up (it's your favorite rock song, for instance) you might say "Crank it up!"

Answer (score 1):

could you `turn` the (TV/radio) `up` ?

The (TV/radio) sound is called "volume".

Comment: Also, "Please turn up (or turn down)  the volume."  as in turning a knob on the radio or TV.

Answer (score 1):

@CarSmack's answer is excellent, but to answer your second question, a "voice" can realistically only belong to a person or a group of people. Radios do not qualify as humans (nor do other inanimate objects that make noise) and therefore "The sound of the radio" is the correct sentence.

Comment: What about the volume as mohamed pointed out? Is it ok to say , the volum of the radio? and if yes, what is the difference then?

Comment: Yes @user2444 you can also say "Turn the volume up." This has the same meaning as when referring to the device or its content.  "Volume" can also refer to a person's voice. A common but informal way to alert a person that they are speaking louder than necessary is simply to say "volume" or "Watch your volume."